# Рабочие столы в ubuntu как в Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я недавно установил ubuntu 20.04 LTS, разобрался как работать с несколькими рабочими столами, вот только нет одной фишки(важной для меня): Когда я переключаюсь на другой(третий) рабочий стол, то на панели задач вижу запущенные приложения только этого рабочего стола. На ubuntu я вижу все запущенные приложения. Можно здесь сделать как на винде?

Comment: Если коротко, то ответ «да, можно конечно».

Comment: Можете пояснить как, или кинуть ссылку на статью пожалуйста?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54994/force-alttab-show-only-active-desktop-apps-in-gnome-shell спасибо, что научились гуглить.